# Is there support of Cloud databases for Mobile Foundation Service in IBM Cloud?

Tags: database, cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, compose-db

Does Mobile Foundation Service in IBM Cloud Public support the new service Cloud Databases for Postgres instead of compose for Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Cloud Foundry service, yes, it will work with Databases for PostgreSQL. All you need to do is create the Databases for PostgreSQL deployment, then you'll create an alias for it. You can do that from the `ibmcloud` CLI using the following command:

```
ibmcloud resource service-alias-create <your alias name> --instance-name <your databases for postgres deployment name>
```

Then you should be able to use that database just like you use Compose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Cloud Database for Postgres is supported as of today. But I surely know that it's in the pipeline(Work-in-progress).

You can submit a request for enhancements via the link provided on the Mobile Foundation [help page](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/)